# Атака клонов или одинаковые ответы

Tags: обсуждение

Навеяно этим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571874/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Система предложила проверить последний ответ на качество. На мой взгляд, ответ мог бы быть более развернутым, но даже в таком виде несет достаточную информацию. Однако я решил открыть сам вопрос. Там я обнаружил еще два таких же ответа.

Есть формулировка для удаленя вопросов-дублей может есть смысл что то подобное сделать и для ответов?

Comment: Попалась сейчас [**похожая ситуация на EnSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17157272/5951529) — 3 одинаковых ответа, данных в течение минуты. Спасибо.

Answer (score 13):

В примере ответы **разные**.

Ответы вполне могут объяснять одно и то же по-разному, это не повод выбирать только один из них как канонический и бороться с остальными. В примере один ответ даёт ссылку на документацию, второй пример использования, третий раскрывает популярные топтанные грабли и ссылку на какой-то сторонний сайт... ладно, это дополнение всё-таки.

Так что здесь никакие меры предпринимать не нужно.

- Когда ответы реально **одинаковые** т. е. имеет место попытка срубить репутации за наглый плагиат, то <kbd>тревога</kbd>><kbd>требуется вмешательство модератора</kbd> и ***мягкое*** объяснение участнику, что он неправ.
- Когда суть одного из ответов целиком охвачена другим существующим ответом, он просто привлечёт меньше голосов. Хотя бывает, если такой ответ содержит меньше малорелевантных деталей по сравнению "со старшим братом", он может представлять даже большую ценность.
  Если вам кажется, что ценности в ответе никакой, можно сказать автору, что он дублирует материал. Автор может проявить сознательность и грохнуть свой ответ. Я сталкивался с такой ситуацией. А если автор не согласен — ну и ладно. Сообщество решит голосами.

Но здесь ни один из перечисленных случаев не имеет место.

Comment: Вот мы тоже одновременно написали примерно одно и то же. Но это тоже хорошо, два раза прочитал — лучше понял.

Comment: Интересно, а можно ли дать два ответа одновременно? Ну то есть с точностью до секунды в timestamp.

Comment: @alexolut сомневаюсь. Тут и менее мощные действия имеют таймауты по три секунды. Но я не проверял :)

Comment: @D-side таймауты очевидны для одного участника, но несколько же работают в параллель. Надо создать тестовый вопрос. Тут вообще есть "песочница"?

Comment: @alexolut а, нескольким участникам сразу? Думаю, что да. Можно узнать точно в Data Explorer, ища ответы с к одинаковым вопросам с одинаковыми таймштампами.

Comment: @D-side это который доступен с 25K? Или я что-то путаю.

Comment: @alexolut путаете с аналитикой. Нет, я про [вот это](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @D-side прикольно, я пока еще до туда не добирался :) Но если там нет точности более 1 секунды, то можно, имхо, замутить скрипт для создания ежесекундного плагиата, чтоб было непонятно кто автор.

Answer (score 10):

В данном случае вопрос тривиален, поэтому и ответы предельно похожие. Два из них даны в интервале двух минут, наверняка второй автор начал писать ответ, когда первый ещё не был опубликован. Либо просто решил, что может ответить лучше, приведя пример кода (и это действительно лучше).

Третий ответ, данный через 40 минут, в принципе ничего нового не вносит, кроме ссылки на обучающий сайт. И лишний раз подчёркивает, что нумерация идёт с нуля, как в обычном массиве. Тоже нормально, автор вправе это опубликовать.

---

Реальная проблема, это когда:

- Автор публикует один и тот же ответ на несколько вопросов (нужно отмечать дубликатом вопрос, а не ответы копировать).
- Автор копирует код из чужого и публикует в своём ответе без указания авторства (это плагиат).

  - Особенно, если это ответы на один и тот же вопрос (а это наглая попытка срубить репутации нахаляву).